# How To Hide View on Specific Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to hide a GridView by setting `drawerGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);` when the ViewPager is on a specific layout. Do I need to implement a `onPageListener` or is there an easier option?

### Launcher.java

```
public class Launcher extends FragmentActivity {

    DrawerAdapter drawerAdapterObject;
    GridView drawerGrid;
    class Package {
        Drawable icon;
        String name;
        String label;
    }
    Package[] packs;
    PackageManager pm;
    ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);


        drawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);
        pm=getPackageManager();
        set_packs();
        drawerAdapterObject = new DrawerAdapter(this, packs);
        drawerGrid.setAdapter(drawerAdapterObject);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(1);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }

    }

    public void set_packs() {
        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> packsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        packs = new Package[packsList.size()];
        for(int I=0;I<packsList.size();I++){
            packs[I]=  new Package();
            packs[I].icon=packsList.get(I).loadIcon(pm);
            packs[I].name=packsList.get(I).activityInfo.packageName;
            packs[I].label=packsList.get(I).loadLabel(pm).toString();
        }

    }
```

### PagerAdapter.java

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:

                return new Fragment1();

            case 1:

                return new Fragment2();

            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

### Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_apps,container,false);
    }

}
```

### Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

        ViewPager viewpager;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_homescreen,container,false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, use addonpagechange listener

Comment: Ok, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in two ways:

1. As you mentioned by using `addOnPageChangedListener`
2. Using callback when your fragment become visible to user

Answer (score 1):

How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager:

try this;

```
  public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
          //hide view here
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

**setUserVisibleHint**

Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user. This hint defaults to true and is persistent across fragment instance state save and restore.

here `isVisibleToUser`  boolean: returns true if this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user (default), false if it is not.

Comment: yes when viewpager is on a specific fragment...`setUserVisibleHint` will return true..so you know that fragment is currently visible

Comment: as you have two fragment you have to overwrite ...`setUserVisibleHint` function in both of them ..

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. Thank you, this is another option i guess.